# How to make horizon work with Promise

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, horizon

```
// Expected something like this
var message = await horizon('message').get(1).fetch().toPromise()

// In real life
horizon('message').get(1).fetch().subscribe((message)=>process(message))

// Simulate
promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  horizon('message').get(1).fetch().subscribe(resolve,reject)
})
```

Is there any easier way to interop promise and horizon's rxjs observable ?

Comment: Trying out Promises with Horizon as well, did you figure this one out?

Comment: @WouterVanherck Sorry, no, currently we don't use horizon yet.